# angular 4 - observable timer in minutes

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I display my timer in minutes instead of seconds?

Here's what I got:

```
export class CustomHeader {

  countDown;
  counter = 36000;

  constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,private alertCtrl: AlertController,public app: App,public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navCtrl: NavController, private webService: WebService, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public auth0: Auth0ServiceProvider, private globalVarsService: GlobalVarsService) {
    this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000)
    .take(this.counter)
    .map(() => --this.counter);
  }

}
```

in my html:

```
<span ion-text>{{countDown  | async}}</span>
```

it's working but it's showing something like this: **35999... 35998...**

> Is there a way to show that data in minutes instead of seconds?

Comment: could you be more explicit on what is your _expected output_? What do you expect to see for example for 35999?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an [Angular Decimal Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe), so your code will look something like this:

```
<span ion-text>{{countDown/60 | number: '1.0-0'}}:{{countDown%60}}</span>
```

The countDown is being divided by 60 to get the minutes, and then run through a pipe to show at least 1 integer and 0 decimals.

You can get the remaining seconds with the % operation.

Answer (score 0):

You scheduled your timer to run each second , in order to make it run each minute you need to do like follow `Observable.timer(60000)` 60000 for 60secs(1 minute)

Comment: @User100696 it give you the same result , the counter is shown every second ?